Jfrog artifactory function rtCreateDockerBuild fails to create a build using digest file
I created docker images and pushed to artifactory using kaniko, with an option to generate a digest file.
The digest file includes the whole path of the images that were pushed to artifactory:
Content of file image-tags-digest-file
techops.artifactory.cec.lab.emc.com/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample:pr_103@sha256:d88b19df428a8b5757de0aa07181cd7d7129eff072bd20ac4727a265e13c2595

However when using rtCreateDockerBuild with the digest file and sourceRepo set to the main repository, the sourceRepo path is added to the image path, results in search image with wrong path (/techops-docker-virtual/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample:pr_103):
Code:
rtCreateDockerBuild(

            serverId: "...",                     
            sourceRepo: "techops-docker-virtual",
            kanikoImageFile: "image-tags-digest-file",
            buildName: "...",
            buildNumber: "..."
        )

How can I use correct path for pushing image by kaniko and find the image in rtCreateDockerBuild that is using image-tags-digest-file ?
console that shows all parameters:
16:56:10  techops.artifactory.cec.lab.emc.com/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample:pr_103@sha256:d88b19df428a8b5757de0aa07181cd7d7129eff072bd20ac4727a265e13c2595
16:56:10  techops.artifactory.cec.lab.emc.com/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample:f1fe5e2@sha256:d88b19df428a8b5757de0aa07181cd7d7129eff072bd20ac4727a265e13c2595
16:56:10  techops.artifactory.cec.lab.emc.com/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample:nightly@sha256:d88b19df428a8b5757de0aa07181cd7d7129eff072bd20ac4727a265e13c2595
[Pipeline] echo
16:56:10  Invoke rtCreateDockerBuild with: server_id=techops-devops-tools, sourceRepo=techops-docker-virtual, kanikoImageFile=image-tags-digest-file, buildName=techops-tools-fastapiexample, buildNumber=f1fe5e2
[Pipeline] rtCreateDockerBuild
16:56:10  Executing command: /bin/sh -c git log --pretty=format:%s -1
16:56:13  [s_applications_JenkinsLib_PR-103] $ java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/s_applications_JenkinsLib_PR-103@tmp/artifactory/javatmpdir -cp /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/s_applications_JenkinsLib_PR-103@tmp/artifactory/cache/artifactory-plugin/4.0.6/* org.jfrog.build.extractor.docker.extractor.BuildDockerCreator
16:56:15  May 30, 2024 1:56:15 PM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger info
16:56:15  INFO: Generating build info for: image-tags-digest-file
16:56:15  May 30, 2024 1:56:15 PM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger info
16:56:15  INFO: Searching manifest for image "techops.artifactory.cec.lab.emc.com/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample:pr_103" in "https://techops.artifactory.cec.lab.emc.com/artifactory" under "techops-docker-virtual" repository
16:56:15  May 30, 2024 1:56:15 PM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger info
16:56:15  INFO: Searching manifest in path: techops-docker-virtual/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample/pr_103
16:56:15  May 30, 2024 1:56:15 PM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger info
16:56:15  INFO: Trying to download manifest from techops-docker-virtual/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample/pr_103/manifest.json
16:56:19  May 30, 2024 1:56:19 PM org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerLogger info
16:56:19  INFO: Fallback for remote/virtual repository. Trying to download fat-manifest from techops-docker-virtual/techops-docker-virtual/devops-tools/examples/fastapiexample/pr_103/list.manifest.json

I've tried to avoid the parameter 'sourceRepo' in rtCreateDockerBuild but it did not help, because 'null' was added to the image path when looking for the image in order to generate a build.
